# Identifying which skin is applied to button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex3

Hi I have a little problem. Is there a way to identify which skin is applied to button? I want to use an if-else statements...

```
//if Skins.skin1 is used
    //statements...
//else if Skins.skin2 is used
   //statements...
```

Comment: You should clarify if you're using the Spark (Flex 4) or Halo/MX (Flex 3) Button.

Comment: I am using Spark in my button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark components that extend `SkinnalbleComponent`, like the `Button` have a [skin](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableComponent.html#skin) property. It is set after Flex attaches the the skin to the component. It could be null, for example, if you create the Button in Actionscript and immediately check the value of `skin`.

You can query the skin for it's type like this:

```
if (button.skin is SkinClass1)
{
    // do something
}
else if (button.skin is SkinClass2)
{
    // etc.
}
```

Or even:

```
switch (true)
{
    case button.skin is SkinClass1:
        // do something
        break;
    case button.skin is SkinClass2:
        //
        break;
}
```